# Change text of y axis labels in ggplot, dissapearing with limits()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am currently trying to change the labels of the y axis in my ggplot but somehow I am not managing two. So what I have are two vectors:

```
x = 1:10

y = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
```

So something like this, although in reality the vectors are much bigger!. So I am trying that, instead of an 0 and 1 at my y axis, I have some other text written, for example "no" and yes". This is how I tried it:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 mydata <- data.frame(x,y)
 ggplot(mydata, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(size=1, color='blue', alpha=1/10) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1), limits=c("no", "yes"))
```

However when I do it like this the labels disappear completely. DOes someone know what am I doing wrong? Thank you!!

Comment: Try changing `limits = c("no", "yes")` to `labels = c("no", "yes")` in your `scale_y_continuous()` line.

Comment: that did it!!! thank you!!!